# Add automatic pagebreak in a .docx document WITHOUT MS Word: is it possible?

Tags: java, c#, pagination, ms-word

I have a plain text and I want to know in his **document.xml** when MS word puts it's page break without opening and saving document with MS word. Is this possible?
I need this features because I'm trying to simulate an on-line text editor and I need to page exactly like MS Word does. My text is written in a simple `div`, I need to know when I have to change the `div` (so the user will see an other withe sheet).

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: Open XML , Aspose, Spire.Doc